# jquery endswith string for selector

Tags: c#, jquery, selector

I am trying to get a jquery selector to `>div:first>.menuItems` of a selector with endwith

```
  var appendingCode =
                    "jQuery('jQuery([id$='DivSiteMenu'])>div:first>.menuItems')" 
                    + ".append("
                            + "'<div class=\"menuItem\" id=\"AdminMenu_CustomQueryTool\">"
                                    + "<a href=\"AdminCategoriesView.aspx\">"
                                        + this.GetNavigationLabel()
                                    + "</a>" 
                            + "</div>" 
                    + "');";
```

But with no success.
How can I write it to be correct in C#?

Comment: You have `'` inside of `'`, should you be escaping them? `\'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your selector is incorrect and as you are using it in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) you have to esacpe quotes

```
var appendingCode = "jQuery('[id$=\"DivSiteMenu\"] > div:first > .menuItems')"
```

Or, You can also use without escaping

```
var appendingCode = "jQuery('[id$=DivSiteMenu] > div:first > .menuItems')"
```